# Ringworld held in place around a Magnetar using Quantum Locking

Tags: hard-science, megastructures, superconductors

[Ringworlds](https://larryniven.fandom.com/wiki/Ringworld) are very interesting superstructures sometimes found in science fiction, but they run afoul of being under so much force that they would rip apart any known materials.

[Magnetars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetar) are Neutron stars with extraordinarily powerful magnetic fields.

[Quantum Locking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDmjoaLp_Pw) is a phenomenon known to hold superconductors at a fixed elevation from a magnet, neither allowing it to fall nor rise.

**Would it be possible to make a Ringworld around a Magnetar using only known materials with the help of type-2 superconductors?**

Assume a ring world that is about 1 AU radius and spins at about 770 miles/second.  Don't worry about habitability or how the superconductors will stay cool enough, I've already got that part figured out.  The superconductors themselves though will have to consist of no more than 1/2 the mass of the ring world.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a bit cold and dark - or have you made arrangements?

Comment: Are u sure about hard science, regular science base, reality check sould be enough for this one

Comment: Also this statement is not correct, "much force that they would rip apart any known materials." U have to inform yourself on how they can be build

Comment: @MolbOrg tagged hard science because I want calculations actually proving if it can or can not work.  Also, I clarified some specs of the ring world, yes, it is true can make one that is 1 AU radius and does not spin fast enough for artificial gravity or you can make it less than 1 AU, but spin for 1G, but doing both is a problem.

Comment: @Nosajimiki make a question about how to build a ringworld, if there is none already, seems u may need it. idk, this question however is quite hard, yeah, why not handwavium   as we seen the thing floating above magnets. i would say magnetar isn't strong enough, field fades as usual 1/r2(not so simple but skipped), size of the thing is 20km, field strength 1e15 gauss, or 1e11 Tesla, so it will be 1T at 20 light secods, 1/25 a.u. so at 1 a.u. it will be 1/625T, where ferrite magnet is 0.5-1T, which seems not enough, but there is no way I can prove that, lol.

Comment: u can shrink the ring, but there is another problem, quite shallow change of the field over quite a distance - and what superconductor locks on is the gradient of the field and how much "holding" force do u get in here is quite a tricky question, and probably it will act as very loose spring and can it be compressed it's another tricky question. Try physics.se - maybe there are guys who can do the research

Comment: in general whatever force there may be it will be a function of gradients of the field, so the gradient may be not big enough even on scale of 10's km's not talking about some iron rod 1m size - it won't fly like in gaus gun despite 1T field all around it, meaning strength of a field is not necessarily that meningfull on static things. but if there are fluctuations or not, does not matter - welcome to electrocuting hell moving at 770miles per second

Comment: The magnetar's gravity scales as 1/r2 . Its magnetic field scales as 1/r3 . the ability to pin depends on field strength * gradient , so more like 1/r4 . Plus the magnetic field must be able to slip through the superconductor without destroying superconductivity, which requires both strong magnetic field but not too strong. All of this needs to be balanced against the gravity of the magnetar, while everything is bathed in a gentle wash of x-rays, gamma rays, and relativistic particles being ejected from the accretion disk around the magnetar. Best luck to whoever is brave enough to try this!

Comment: OK, my answer was just out and out wrong.  Just now I looked up SGR 0525-66 and using the apparent magnitude of 24 and distance 165000 came up with an absolute magnitude (5.47) only *slightly* dimmer than the Sun.  And per [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/421517/what-will-happen-if-a-magnetar-gets-close-to-earth) the field is only 1 T at 100,000 km!  (Starting from 20 km matters).  And then PcMan mentioned r^4 because the gradient matters.  Maybe I ought to change this to "Field? What magnetic field?" but I want a minute to think about it.

Comment: If you use cataclystical fermions in an anhydrous mixture with Maxwellian bosons,  it will interact with the Graxmern field in such a way that integral multivane constituency is maintained. This allows the ENF field to interlace with the Graxmern field to produce gravitronic disruption agents. The ring will preserve its bistabilic integrity. But meeting the hard science tag with this construction? Not likely.

Comment: @PcMan, hm hm, yes it is a dipole so 1/r3 is correct one, good u pointed it out. Btw won't u sum things up and write no answer? my upvote then guaranteed - no-answer is also an answer.

Comment: @MolbOrg I do not know if there *is* an answer or not. I can vaguely identify the forces in action, but to quantize them? Good grief! But whether it works or not, it will be a very hostile environment, and will require tech very much up to SunDiver level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR: No.**

I spent ages faffing about with superconductor parameters and pinning force densities and tensile forces before realising that the underlying premise was all wrong.

---

Let us first consider the magnetic field of a magnetar... it is famously [Quite Strong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetar#Magnetic_field). But consider also that magnetars are pretty small: 10km radius.

The field strength of a magnetic dipole, such as that posessed by your magnetar, follows an [inverse *cube* distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole). We can compute the field strength at some point relative to a dipole like this:

$$ B(\mathbf{r}) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \left [ \frac{3\mathbf{r}(\mathbf{m} \cdot \mathbf{r})}{r^5} - \frac{\mathbf{m}}{r^3} \right ] $$

where $\mathbf{m}$ is the magnetic dipole moment of the magnetar, and $\mathbf{r}$ is where we're trying to compute the field strength. If we just consider the field strength on the magnetic equator of the magnetar (or in its magnetic equatorial plane in space around the star) where our magnetic axis $\mathbf{m}$ is perpendicular to our radial vector $\mathbf{r}$ this all nicely devolves to a simple $ B(r) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \frac{2m}{r^3}$

If our magnetar has a magnetic moment of ~10<sup>29</sup>Am<sup>2</sup> and a radius of 10km, it will have a surface magnetic field strength of ~2 x 10<sup>10</sup>T, which is a [plausible figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetar#Magnetic_field). AT 1000km from the centre of the star, the field strength is 20kT. At 10000km, 20T. At the radius of our own Sun, ~695700km, the field strength is a mere **60μT**. For comparison, the Sun's surface magnetic field is more like 100-200μT.

By the time you get out to 1AU the magnetic field is negligible. The strength of the Sun's magnetic field at Earth's orbit is higher than people expect, possibly due to [magnetohydrodynamic reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interplanetary_magnetic_field#Magnetic_field_at_Earth_orbit) though nobody seems entirely sure (but [see also](https://xkcd.com/1851/)). The Sun generates a solar wind to provide these MHD effects but neutron stars aren't going to have much of that because they're not doing a whole lot of fusion, don't have a whole lot of spare mass any more and have quite a lot of gravity at their surface. Your 1AU ringworld simply can't benefit from the magnetar's amazing magnetic field.

Incidentally, a radius of more like ~27144km will given you an ambient field strength of ~1T which is starting to be strong enough to be interesting... shame about the 25.7 kilogee gravity field. By the time the gravitational pull of the magnetar has dropped to a mere 1 gee (at about 0.029AU) the magnetic field has dropped to a paltry 0.24μT, which could well be lower than the [galactic magnetic field strength](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Galactic_magnetic_fields) where your magnetar is (it is 6μT in our own galactic neighbourhood, for example).

---

*edit: MolbOrg pointed out an error in an earlier version of this section which has now been corrected.*

One small concern I'd have (and which was touched upon in the comments to the question) is the existence of magnetic field gradients. As can be seen in videos of little maglev experiments, a type-II superconductor can move freely within a constant magnetic field. That might give your ring the opportunity to move towards or away from the parent star, perhaps even developing hula-hoop like instabilities which would play havoc with the centrifugal gravity. It might have to be very deep in the radial direction, like a giant solid version of Saturn's rings, rather than the common vision of a ringworld which is a little more like a wedding ring in shape. This kind of deep, flat shape might also be required to develop sufficient pinning force, but as the above section has shown that your design is basically impossible I won't elaborate on this here.

Note also that magnetar magnetic fields are [quite short lived](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.2679)... the all the energy in the field will have largely radiated away in under a few million years, and quite possibly as few as [10000 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetar#Description). That puts a pretty tight timescale on the construction and use of your magnetic megastructure.

---

Honestly though, this is a good thing. Its hard to live in a strong magnetic field... [it isn't recommended](https://blink.ucsd.edu/safety/radiation/magnet/limits.html) that humans are exposed to even as much as a couple of teslas even briefly, and even a thousandth of that is problematic. Even a uniform magnetic field measured in milliteslas represents a projectile hazard from ferrous objects. It'll be bad news for all sorts of electrical and electronic equipment.

Even if you world could be made, it would be inhospitable for almost everything.

Comment: Field in equaterial plane should be axial symmetrical, so is not possible to distinguish angular position, so rotation is possible, it just not a great idea because of lawrence effects.

Comment: @MolbOrg (also, was lawrence effect intended to be lorentz effect? I haven't found any referrences to a lawrence effect in magnetism, but maybe I just asked the wrong questions)

Comment: Lorentz effect for sure, will blame it on spellchecker again. "pinned" objects to be able to rotate or slide" - sliding is easy here as an example https://youtu.be/zPqEEZa2Gis?t=30 - there is plenty of that stuff "superconductor on track". the reason seems quite obiviou when a magnet is smaller compared to a superconductor, the field is more uneven on the scale of that superconductor,  then yes it catches superconductor in 3 points, so to speak. But if there is a trajectory where the field isn't much different in configuration from other points of that trajectory it will be able to move on it.

Comment: @MolbOrg right, gotcha. I wonder though, it might be possible to induce a hula-hoop style instability in this sort of ring if it were spinning if it were not perfectly centred, or there were some transient disruption of the parent star's magnetic field. I guess it would matter more if the whole idea were more plausible in the first place ;-)

Comment: some changes in the field, perturbations of the ring, with speeds involved - yeah it would be a spectacular scene. Could a ring be stable because of the magnetic field - hard to tell, some potential is there, but will it matter needs some calculations and better considerations of what happens on the superconductor. Some resistance will be there besides gravity effects. idk, it just too many flaws besides that, to be bothered by that, so is it for me.